# Logical Indexing Failing when Matrix is loaded by matfile

Tags: matlab, indexing, mat-file

I have a matrix that was stored in a `.mat` file, and was then reloaded in matlab via the function `matfile`. I also have a logical index, like logical([1 0 1 0]), that I want to apply to the loaded matrix:

```
results = matfile('results.mat');
% id is my logical vector of the appropriate size
% IV is a matrix stored in results.mat
newIV = results.IV(:,id);
```

However, I am running into a problem and getting this error:

```
'IV' cannot be indexed with class 'logical'. Indices must be numeric.
```

I do not understand what is causing this issue. I have been using this same code before and it was working, the only thing was that I did not have to load the struct results before, I already had it in memory. 
It gets weirder; this works:

```
IV = results.IV;
newIV = IV(:,id); % this works somehow
```

This also works:

```
results_raw = matfile('results.mat');
results = struct('IV',results_raw.IV);
newIV = IV(:,id); % this also works!!! why matlab, why???
```

I also tried resaving the `results.mat` file using the `-v7.3` flag, but it did not solve the problem. The issue seems to be with loading the `.mat` file, because I created a struct with a matrix and used logical indexing and it worked fine.

**Question:** why does indexing work when I pass `results.IV` to `IV`? how can I make it work with `results.IV`?

Thanks for helping!!! :D

Comment: Seems you can not, like other limitations, as documented explicitly in the `matfile` page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html#bt2ft8s-6   When you assign the data to another variable, it states as a new data type, with all the data in the workspace, has nothing to do with `matfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adiel said in questions comments. You can't use `logical` indices.
So, convert `logical` indices to `numeric` indices using `find`.

```
results = matfile('results.mat');
% id is my logical vector of the appropriate size
% IV is a matrix stored in results.mat
newIV = results.IV(:,find(id));
```

Comment: This will only work if `id` is of the same dimension of `results.IV`. Since `results.IV` is a matrix, we would need `id` to be a matrix so that `find(id)` works as intended. If `id` is a vector, in the case of linear indexing, then even `find(id)` will not work, as `matfile does not support linear indexing`. The solution seems to be copying `results.IV` to a matrix in the workspace.